Would I be able to get an undergrad degree in CS and the get a PHD in mathematics?
Would it hurt my chances? Obviously if i was applying from a history undergrad to math PHD it wouldn't help, but I dont know if a CS BS would hurt with my math PHD, because CS is just math right?

What makes you think ‘CS is just math,’ out of curiosity?

Depending on which country your applying in and which math courses you've taken this could be a duplicate of one of How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?, How feasible is it to pursue PhD in mathematics for a computer science undergrad?, Applying to math PhD with CS undergrad, What do I need to do to move from a CS major to a math PhD
